# Mocking a fake configuration during a unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have code that does something like this

```
from custom_paths import CONFIG_PATH

class SomethingCool:
    def __init__(self, filepath: str) -> None:
        with open(os.path.join(CONFIG_PATH, filepath)) as fd:
            self.config = yaml.safe_load(fd)

        blah blah do something
```

However during a unit test, I want the `config_path` to point somewhere else. We can assume it points to `foobuzz/configs` during normal times and then `tests/foobuzz/configs` during testing (which is declared by the `TESTS_PATH` variable).  However, every time I try to run, it always points to the usual directory and I'm not finding anything in pytest, monkeypatch, or SO that specifically addresses this.

```
import custom_paths

def return_fake_path():
    return os.path.join(
        TESTS_PATH,
        "configs"
    )

def test_config_simple(monkeypatch):
    """
    Simple test to see if config is correct
    """
    monkeypatch.setattr(custom_paths, "CONFIG_PATH", return_fake_path)
    coolstuff = SomethingCool("test.yml")
    assert something something
```

I've also tried this out as well

```
FAKE_CONFIG_PATH = os.path.join(
   TESTS_PATH,
   "configs"
)

@mock.patch("custom_paths.CONFIG_PATH", FAKE_CONFIG_PATH)
def test_config_simple():
    """
    Simple test to see if config is correct
    """
    coolstuff = SomethingCool("test.yml")
    assert something something
```

I feel this should be easy but not finding anything about dynamically changing static variables during testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unittest library's *mock_open*

```
mock_config = {...}
with patch("builtins.open", mock_open(read_data=mock_config)) as mock_file:
    ...
```

This will mock out the built-in open functionality during your test and replace its result with a desired mock. Check out the options available to mock_open to see what will fit your use cases.

Comment: Wow, that's cool. Didn't know this could be done!